# Android Studio Alarm Service Not Starting Automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alarms

I am trying to develop a simple alarm clock app in Android Studio, but I am having trouble figuring out how to use the `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` properly.

In my `MainActivity` I have instantiated everything I need for the `AlarmManager` (`Intent`, `PendingIntent`, and I am using a Calendar to hold the time received from a `TimePicker`). I have this line in a button's `onClick` event

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The receiver is called `AlarmReceiver` and in its `onReceive()` I have, for now,

```
Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.e("Receiver", "Receiver entered");
```

For testing purposes, I set the alarm time to be one minute from the current time whenever I debug the app. After setting the time, I press the button which sets the `AlarmManager`. The Toast message and Log message don't show up on their own once the time becomes the alarm time. They only show up if I press the button when the time is within the minute that is the alarm time.

For example if alarm time is 3:00, and current time is 2:59 and I have pressed the button to set the `AlarmManager`. When it becomes 3:00, the messages don't show. They will only show if I press the button within the minute of 3:00.

Is this the normal behavior? If so how do I set it up so that the messages show automatically once everything is set so that I can extend it to a ringtone later?

I have ensured that the time values are right and that the receiver is specified in the `manifest`

Comment: Did you pass Intent to start Service??

Comment: Yes I did. I have added a service to play a mp3 file for testing purposes. The problem is that it is still not starting automatically when the current time is at the alarm time. I have to press the button

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this:

```
private static void setUpAlarm(final Context context, final Intent               intent, final int timeInterval){
final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)       context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, timeInterval, intent, 0);
am.cancel(pi);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    final AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
    am.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
}
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
else
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInterval, pi);
}
```

Comment: futhermore `setAlarmClock` is really awful

Answer (score 0):

I'm really recommend to use this code:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
    } else if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
        } else {
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
        }
```